# Eclipse oddity: UnsatisfiedLinkError in JNI code

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface

We have a C++ DLL that we call from JNI.

Under Java 1.6.0_26, it runs and debugs perfectly under Eclipse. However if we switch the JRE to 1.6.0_24 it will run fine, but if we try to *debug* we get an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Any ideas, we're all stumped?

Comment: You haven't installed the DLL into the 1.6.0_26 lib directory or something?

Comment: No, it sits in an independent directory.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant here, but in Linux JVM tries to load libraries, by adding an "_g" to the library name. I don't know how it is in Windows though. Point is in debug mode, the JVM tries to load a different librarry

Comment: hi jogbanito - that would make sense were it not for the fact that it works just fine under 1.6.0_26.

The DLL uses the JNI for 1.6.0_26 JDK - might that be of relevance?

Comment: update: looks like it might not be the Java version at all. our app editor uses SWT, and the failure seems to be that it can't find SWT when debugging. Presumably when running from Eclipse, SWT is already loaded, but the debug version may not have the same relationship to SWT (the dll sits inside a JAR file and is extracted on demand). so how does SWT get bundled with apps?

Answer (score 0):

Are you debugging your SWT application from the command line or still within Eclipse? You need to make sure the SWT jar file is in the -classpath / -cp list.

It's very likely that running within Eclipse, the project settings have added it for you already, so you could take a peek at the command line options Eclipse is using to run the project and copy the classpath entries you need.